# Is there a CoffeeScript equivalent to the ruby koans?

Tags: coffeescript

I found several JavaScript testing frameworks with a quick Google search: [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/), [jsUnity](http://jsunity.com/), [JSpec](http://visionmedia.github.com/jspec/), [YUI Test](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuitest/), [JsUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit), [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit)

I'm sure that this is by no means an exhaustive list.

**Has anyone written CoffeeScript koans** in one of these frameworks, similar to the [EdgeCase ruby koans](http://rubykoans.com/)?

I really enjoyed going through them and going through the [python-koans](http://python-koans.appspot.com/). Each exercise significantly improved my language comfort level, and I'm really hoping that similar exercises exist for CoffeeScript.

Comment: Not that I know of... might be a project to work on, though.  The Ruby Koans are epic! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try Googling "CoffeeScript Koans"? :)

https://github.com/sleepyfox/coffeescript-koans

(They're powered by [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/).)

Comment: I did & this didn't come up. Google localization at your service! Thanks @trevor-burnham.

Comment: The trick is to go to github and search for koans there